# Visual Studio Code download node.d.ts

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm testing the new code editor from Microsoft : Visual Studio Code.

I'm under Windows 7 and i'm trying this example : https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs

But when i try to add `/// <reference path="/typings/node/node.d.ts"/>`

like it is said in the example. It does'nt work. The file is never downloaded and i don't know where i can find it.

Is someone knows how to fix that ? Is it a bug or the problem come from my machine ?

Comment: You need to have `node.d.ts` located at the filepath `/typings/node/` on your machine (note that `/typings/` is **not** the same as `typings/` and `/typings` will resolve to `C:/typings` on most windows installations). It will not be downloaded for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TSD** is TypeScript Definition, while [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a typed superset of JavaScript from Microsoft that compiles to plain JavaScript. You don't need to understand these if you just want to use VSCode to develop common JavaScript-based node.js projects like me.

To solve your problem, I think a better way is to install the **TSD package manager** as a global module. This will enable you to use the command ***tsd*** globally.

```
npm install tsd@next -g
```

Then go to the root folder of your project, and type

```
tsd install node
```

This will automatically create a folder 'typings/node' with a .ts file named 'node.d'.

If you also need IntelliSense for third party modules like express.js or async.js, you can just add them by yourself

```
tsd install express
```

Just like 'npm' which you already be familiar with is the package manager for node.js, 'tsd' is the package manager for TypeScript Definition (but not for TypeScript itself)

There's a list here showing the available repositories.

> http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/

Once you download all the .tsd files into the 'typings' folder, you still have to manually put these special comments at the beginning of each .js files to help VSCode  look up the definitions for node and express, so now VSCode knows the API details of the classes and functions.

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="typings/express/express.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: Thanks with tsd manual installation it works. :) I thinks it's a proxy problem. I don't have this problem on my personal computer at home it works with the automatic code tool.

Comment: For me, the tsd installs, but then fails with the error "Unhandled stream error in pipe."  It won't download the file from there either.  I'll join others in saying that this worked great from my personal computer at home, and failed miserably from my work computer behind a proxy.

Comment: In VSCode 0.10.1 you don't need to add the references. It just works

Comment: ***tsd*** is deprecated as you can see in [documentation](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). Use [***typings***](https://github.com/typings/typings)!

Comment: typings is also marked as deprecated on the repo description

Comment: @snarf @Rami The modern way is `npm install --save @types/node`.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried last night and it worked fine.

You shouldn't put the reference by yourself. You should let VS Code do it for you by pressing "Ctrl + ." (thats the dot key you should press) on the marked __dirname and choosing the option for the TypeScript Definition file as said on the website.

VS Code will create the directories structure under your project folder, download the file and add the reference to your app.js express application.

Comment: Yes that what i've done but it does'nt work. Maybe because there is a proxy in my company. I will try on my personal computer this evening to see if there is a difference.

Comment: On my personal computer it works fine too. I'm pretty sure that is a proxy problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with angular and this is how I got it to work for me: It looks like the problem was that VSCode failed to download the file and create the directories. I googled angular.d.ts and found it on [GitHub - DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts)

I created "typings/angularj/" folders and added the file and now intellisense is working for angular :)

So just grab the "node.d.ts" file instead of from DefinitelyTyped and it should work for you as well.

Comment: link goes to a 404

Answer (score 0):

As @HenryLi mentioned, **you need to get a file with type definitions** for Node. However TSD has been deprecated for quite a while now. Worry not, however! Now the type definitions are managed directly by Microsoft and bundled right through `npm`!

**To solve your problem, it's enough to run this command**:

```
npm install --save -g @types/node
```

Comment: I ran the command as mentioned and got the success message. + @types/node@13.13.5
added 1 package from 43 contributors in 0.339s But cannot find where is the file node.d.ts that I need to reference in my .ts file inside Visual Studio. @m93a

Comment: It should be in `node_modules/@types/node`.

Answer (score -2):

(Edit: VS Code needs me to open a directory, and not a single file to let intellisense work well)

Same problem for me.

This does not work:

> Add /// reference to 'node/node.d.ts'

Nothing happens...

[image]

But this does work, VS Code is responding. (Edit: stops the warning, but no auto-completion this way):

> Mark '__dirname' as global

[image]

Comment: That only removes the warning. You will not get any intellisense for the `__dirname` identifier this way.